# Why is the connection between a python motor client and a mongoDB being dropped for about 50% of queries?

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, pymongo, fastapi

I'm seeing odd behavior in my application

I have a graphQL python application that lives in a docker container and is using FastAPI and Uvicorn. It connects to a MongoDB in another docker container using Motor. This is run in a Kubernetes instance.

About 50% of the time, but with no real pattern, I won't get results back. The other 50% of the time it works fine.

Based on the mongodb logs it looks like the python application is closing the connection before the response can be sent back. This is not a long running query (< 10ms). Additionally I've tried to set the various timeouts in Motor/PyMongo very high (~3600s) but still get the same behavior.

Client Initialization:

```
    try:
        # kwargs contains username, password, connectTimeoutMS, socketTimeoutMS, serverSelectionTimeoutMS
        return AsyncIOMotorClient(host, port, appname=appname, connect=True, **kwargs)
    except:
        #log it
```

The Query Code:

```
def callQuery(vendor, name):
    match_query = {
        "$match": {
            "_id.product_vendor": vendor,
            "_id.product_name": name,
        }
    }
    add_fields = {
        "$addFields": {
            "product_name": "$_id.product_name",
            "product_vendor": "$_id.product_vendor",
        }
    }
    project = {"$project": {"_id": 0}}
    cursor = collection.aggregate([match_query, add_fields, project])
    products = await cursor.to_list(length=None) # line 173 in product_lookup to compare to bt below

def submit_aggregation(pipeline: List[dict], collection, **kwargs):                                                                                        
    return collection.aggregate(pipeline, **kwargs)
```

MongoDB logs:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22934,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Starting server-side compression negotiation"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22935,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Compression negotiation not requested by client"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23905,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Using exhaust for isMaster or hello protocol"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"admin.$cmd","appName":"mappingapi","command":{"hello":1,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"619d4e56e9dc669ff6ade24b"},"counter":0},"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"$db":"admin","$readPreference":{"mode":"primary"}},"numYields":0,"reslen":313,"locks":{},"remote":"127.0.0.1:41430","protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":25787,"knownOps":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"-",        "id":5127803, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Released the Client","attr":{"client":"conn5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"-",        "id":5127801, "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Setting the Client","attr":{"client":"conn5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"COMMAND",  "id":21965,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"About to run the command","attr":{"db":"admin","commandArgs":{"hello":1,"topologyVersion":{"processId":{"$oid":"619d4e56e9dc669ff6ade24b"},"counter":0},"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000,"$db":"admin","$readPreference":{"mode":"primary"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T20:59:25.690+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"FTDC",     "id":23904,   "ctx":"conn5","msg":"Using maxAwaitTimeMS for awaitable hello protocol","attr":{"maxAwaitTimeMS":10000}}
```

Backtrace of the disconnect from the python client:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 844, in handle_future_result
    resolve(future.result())
  File "./mappingdb/api.py", line 247, in resolve_productdbProducts
    client=get_pdb_client(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/productdata/_utils.py", line 42, in func_future
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/productdata/query.py", line 173, in product_lookup
    products = await cursor.to_list(length=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/motor/core.py", line 1372, in _to_list
    result = get_more_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/motor/core.py", line 1611, in _on_started
    pymongo_cursor = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2507, in aggregate
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2421, in _aggregate
    retryable=not cmd._performs_write)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1525, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, secondary_ok)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/aggregation.py", line 149, in get_cursor
    user_fields=self._user_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 726, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 929, in _raise_connection_failure
    _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 238, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise NetworkTimeout(msg)
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: productdb:27017: timed out
```

Comment: When connection is not working fine, could you check if pods are running using `kubectl get pods` command? Are both Python app and MongoDB app are running in Kubernetes? Could you please share more information how did you setup your Kubernetes cluster, which solution did you used - some cloud provider solution or bare-metal (kubeadm, kubespray etc...)?

Comment: Both the Python and MongoDB containers are up and not showing any restarts. They are different pods but in the same namespace. We're using Kubespray with metallb for load balancing and linkerd as the service mesh (made mongodb an opaque connection but that didn't help).